# Why does IndexOf(Vb6ChrW(65533)) return 0 if not found?

Tags: string, vb.net

I am baffled what is going on here:

```
Dim sSearchIn As String = "Bla"

Dim sSearchFor As String = Vb6ChrW(65533) 'This results in the string "�"

Dim i As Integer = sSearchIn.IndexOf(sSearchFor, 0)
```

I expect "i" to be -1 because the string "�" does not exist in the string "Bla".

However, "i" is 0.

What am I missing?

Thank you!

```
Public Function Vb6ChrW(ByVal uKeyCode As Integer) As String

    Dim nChar As Char = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(uKeyCode)
    Return New String(nChar, 1)

End Function
```

Comment: `Dim i As Integer = sSearchIn.IndexOf(ChrW(65533))`

Comment: According to the MSDN, `IndexOf` removes "ignorable characters". And, it also says that "If value is Empty, the return value is startIndex".  So I guess it is treating `sSearchFor` as an empty string because it has an ignorable character? I think the reason @Jimi's code works is that `ChrW` returns a `Char` and so a different overload of `IndexOf` is called.

Comment: I.e., better not to convert to string a [non-character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Non-characters). Use the Char directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are performing [culture-sensitive search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-6.0#system-string-indexof(system-string-system-int32)). It is behaving as documented:

> In a culture-sensitive search, if `value` contains an ignorable character, the result is equivalent to searching with that character removed. If value consists only of one or more ignorable characters, the `IndexOf(String, Int32)` method always returns `startIndex`

If you wanted a char-code-level search, you should have used

```vb
sSearchIn.IndexOf(sSearchFor, StringComparison.Ordinal)
```

, that gives -1 as you expect.

You should also turn [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) so that it correctly brakes your `Vb6ChrW` function that you don't need in the first place because [`ChrW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.chrw?view=net-6.0#microsoft-visualbasic-strings-chrw(system-int32)) exists.

Comment: Another reference in the Remarks here  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-6.0#system-string-indexof(system-string-system-int32)

Comment: @dbasnett Isn't that the same link as the one already in the answer?

Comment: not sure.  Maybe.